# owner/group getting set to `82`

Tags: group, chown, ownership

I am running a [Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando) dev environment on a simple [dummy LAMP application](https://github.com/acobster/lando-lamp-dummy), as a way to test my custom [Lando plugin](https://github.com/sitecrafting/lando-beanstalkd/tree/console) (working off the `console` branch). (Lando is a tool for running local dev environments, with goals similar to Vagrant but built atop Docker Compose.)

Every once in a while - I have not discerned a pattern yet - running a lando command such as `lando start`, `lando info`, or `lando stop` from within my app directory, `~/workspace/lamp`, will set the owner and group of that working directory to `82`. When this happens, it also applies the same ownership/group to `~/.lando`, Lando's directory for userland config and data files. There is no such user or group on my machine.

```
~/workspace/lamp $ ls -la
total 64
drwxrwxr-x  5      82      82  4096 Dec 10 19:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 36 ctamayo ctamayo  4096 Dec 13 12:11 ..
-rw-r--r--  1      82      82   289 Nov  3 17:45 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1      82      82  4064 Nov  3 17:45 composer.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1      82      82    45 Nov  3 17:58 .env
drwxrwxr-x  8      82      82  4096 Dec 10 19:14 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1      82      82    35 Nov  3 17:46 .gitignore
-rw-rw-r--  1      82      82   284 Dec  8 16:52 .lando.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1      82      82 22770 Dec 15 09:51 stderr.log
drwxr-xr-x  5      82      82  4096 Nov  3 17:45 vendor
drwxrwxr-x  2      82      82  4096 Nov  3 18:09 www
~/workspace/lamp $ cd ~/.lando
~/.lando $ ls -la
total 52
drwxrwxr-x 10 82      82 4096 Dec  8 16:57 .
drwx------ 79 82      82 4096 Dec 15 10:49 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 82      82  670 Dec  8 16:05 appRegistry.json
drwxrwxr-x  2 82      82 4096 Nov 27 20:53 cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 82      82  171 Dec  8 16:57 config.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 82      82   36 Oct 24 10:59 .instance.id
drwxr-xr-x  3 82      82 4096 Oct 24 13:15 keys
drwxrwxr-x  2 82      82 4096 Oct 24 11:55 logs
drwxrwxr-x  2 82      82 4096 Dec  1 09:57 plugins
drwxrwxr-x  2 82      82 4096 Oct 24 11:04 proxy
drwxrwxr-x  3 82      82 4096 Oct 24 10:59 services
drwxrwxr-x 17 82      82 4096 Nov 21 10:38 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  2 82      82 4096 Oct 24 12:55 util
~/.lando $ sudo grep 82 /etc/passwd
~/.lando $ groups
ctamayo adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker
~/.lando $ sudo groups
root
~/.lando $
```

### Troubleshooting, v1.0

Using `strace`, I have tried pinpointing the system call that makes these changes. I am an `strace` n00b so I may be doing it wrong, but here's my debugging technique so far...

I put this helper script in my path that just runs the `lando` commands over and over until they fail (I also have not yet discerned a pattern in *how long* it takes to fail, or which command it fails on):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

while :
do
  echo starting lando
  lando start
  echo lando info
  lando info
  echo stopping lando
  lando stop
done
```

I run this and pipe stderr into the file `stderr.log`...

```
~/workspace/lamp $ strace 2>stderr.log testlando.bash
```

...while tailing that file looking for `82` or `chown` in another window:

```
~/workspace/lamp $ tail -f tail -f stderr.log | egrep '\b82\b|chown'

# .........wait forever........
```

Surprisingly, there is literally no output of the `tail` command (^1), despite the fact that my bash script eventually fails and the ownership and group are set on the two directories as described above.

(The single exception I've seen is this output, which I *think* is purely coincidental: `--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=9941, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=82, si_stime=6} ---`)

The output of the bash script (originating from the `lando` commands within - including tons of debug output from my Lando plugin) is always something like:

```
   starting lando

   BOOMSHAKALAKA!!!

   Your app has started up correctly.
   Here are some vitals:

    NAME            lamp                                       
    LOCATION        /home/ctamayo/workspace/lamp               
    SERVICES        appserver, database, cache, queue, console 

    APPSERVER URLS  https://localhost:32788                    
                    http://localhost:32789                     
                    http://lamp.lndo.site:8000                 
                    https://lamp.lndo.site                     

    CONSOLE URLS    http://beanstalk.lamp.lndo.site:8000       
                    https://beanstalk.lamp.lndo.site           

   lando info
   beanstalkd info
   { image: 'schickling/beanstalkd:latest',
     ports: [ '11333:11300' ],
     command: 'beanstalkd -p 11300',
     entrypoint: '/lando-entrypoint.sh',
     volumes: 
      [ '$LANDO_ENGINE_SCRIPTS_DIR/lando-entrypoint.sh:/lando-entrypoint.sh',
        '$LANDO_APP_ROOT_BIND:/app',
        '$LANDO_ENGINE_HOME:/user',
        '$LANDO_ENGINE_SCRIPTS_DIR/user-perms.sh:/user-perms.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/scripts/load-keys.sh:/scripts/load-keys.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/helpers/mysql-import.sh:/helpers/mysql-import.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/helpers/mysql-export.sh:/helpers/mysql-export.sh' ],
     environment: 
      { LANDO_SERVICE_NAME: 'queue',
        LANDO_SERVICE_TYPE: 'beanstalkd',
        LANDO_MOUNT: '/app',
        LANDO: 'ON',
        LANDO_HOST_OS: 'linux',
        LANDO_HOST_UID: '1000',
        LANDO_HOST_GID: '1000',
        LANDO_HOST_IP: '10.0.10.20',
        LANDO_APP_ROOT: '/home/ctamayo/workspace/lamp',
        LANDO_APP_NAME: 'lamp',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_USER: 'www-data',            '$LANDO_ENGINE_SCRIPTS_DIR/user-perms.sh:/user-perms.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/scripts/load-keys.sh:/scripts/load-keys.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/helpers/mysql-import.sh:/helpers/mysql-import.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/helpers/mysql-export.sh:/helpers/mysql-export.sh' ],
     environment: 
      { LANDO_SERVICE_NAME: 'console',
        LANDO_SERVICE_TYPE: 'beanstalkd_console',
        LANDO_MOUNT: '/app',
        LANDO: 'ON',
        LANDO_HOST_OS: 'linux',
        LANDO_HOST_UID: '1000',
        LANDO_HOST_GID: '1000',
        LANDO_HOST_IP: '10.0.10.20',
        LANDO_APP_ROOT: '/home/ctamayo/workspace/lamp',
        LANDO_APP_NAME: 'lamp',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_USER: 'www-data',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_GROUP: 'www-data',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_UID: '33',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_GID: '33',
        LANDO_LOAD_PP_KEYS: 'false',
        COLUMNS: 256,
        FOO: 'barrrrr',
        REDIS_HOST: 'cache',
        REDIS_PORT: '6379' },
     labels: { 'io.lando.container': 'TRUE' },
        LANDO_WEBROOT_GROUP: 'www-data',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_UID: '33',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_GID: '33',
        LANDO_LOAD_PP_KEYS: 'false',
        COLUMNS: 256,
        FOO: 'barrrrr',
        REDIS_HOST: 'cache',
        REDIS_PORT: '6379' },
     labels: { 'io.lando.container': 'TRUE' },
     type: 'beanstalkd',
     portforward: 11333,
     _app: 'lamp',
     _root: '/home/ctamayo/workspace/lamp',
     _mount: '/app',
     version: 'latest' }
   console info
   { image: 'schickling/beanstalkd-console:latest',
     ports: [ 2080 ],
     command: 'php -S 0.0.0.0:2080 -t /source/public',
     entrypoint: '/lando-entrypoint.sh',
     volumes: 
      [ '$LANDO_ENGINE_SCRIPTS_DIR/lando-entrypoint.sh:/lando-entrypoint.sh',
        '$LANDO_APP_ROOT_BIND:/app',
        '$LANDO_ENGINE_HOME:/user',
        '$LANDO_ENGINE_SCRIPTS_DIR/user-perms.sh:/user-perms.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/scripts/load-keys.sh:/scripts/load-keys.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/helpers/mysql-import.sh:/helpers/mysql-import.sh',
        '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/helpers/mysql-export.sh:/helpers/mysql-export.sh' ],
     environment: 
      { LANDO_SERVICE_NAME: 'console',
        LANDO_SERVICE_TYPE: 'beanstalkd_console',
        LANDO_MOUNT: '/app',
        LANDO: 'ON',
        LANDO_HOST_OS: 'linux',
        LANDO_HOST_UID: '1000',
        LANDO_HOST_GID: '1000',
        LANDO_HOST_IP: '10.0.10.20',
        LANDO_APP_ROOT: '/home/ctamayo/workspace/lamp',
        LANDO_APP_NAME: 'lamp',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_USER: 'www-data',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_GROUP: 'www-data',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_UID: '33',
        LANDO_WEBROOT_GID: '33',
        LANDO_LOAD_PP_KEYS: 'false',
        COLUMNS: 256,
        FOO: 'barrrrr',
        REDIS_HOST: 'cache',
        REDIS_PORT: '6379' },
     labels: { 'io.lando.container': 'TRUE' },
     type: 'beanstalkd_console',
     _app: 'lamp',
     _root: '/home/ctamayo/workspace/lamp',
     _mount: '/app',
     version: 'latest' }
   undefined
   {
     "appserver": {
       "type": "php",
       "version": "7.1",
       "via": "apache",
       "webroot": "www",
       "urls": [
         "https://localhost:32788",
         "http://localhost:32789",
         "http://lamp.lndo.site:8000",
         "https://lamp.lndo.site"
       ]
     },
     "database": {
       "type": "mysql",
       "version": "latest",
       "creds": {
         "user": "lamp",
         "password": "lamp",
         "database": "lamp"
       },
       "internal_connection": {
         "host": "database",
         "port": 3306
       },
       "external_connection": {
         "host": "localhost",
         "port": "32773"
       }
     },
     "cache": {
       "type": "redis",
       "version": "latest",
       "internal_connection": {
         "host": "cache",
         "port": 6379
       },
       "external_connection": {
         "host": "localhost",
         "port": "not forwarded"
       }
     },
     "queue": {
       "type": "beanstalkd",
       "version": "latest",
       "internal_connection": {
         "host": "queue",
         "port": 11300
       },
       "external_connection": {
         "host": "localhost",
         "port": "11333"
       }
     },
     "console": {
       "type": "beanstalkd_console",
       "version": "latest",
       "internal_connection": {
         "host": "console",
         "port": 2080
       },
       "external_connection": {
         "host": "localhost",
         "port": 2080
       },
       "urls": [
         "http://beanstalk.lamp.lndo.site:8000",
         "https://beanstalk.lamp.lndo.site"
       ]
     }
   }
   stopping lando
   App stopped!
   starting lando

   BOOMSHAKALAKA!!!

   Your app has started up correctly.
   Here are some vitals:

    NAME            lamp                                       
    LOCATION        /home/ctamayo/workspace/lamp               
    SERVICES        appserver, database, cache, queue, console 

    APPSERVER URLS  https://localhost:32797                    
                    http://localhost:32798                     
                    http://lamp.lndo.site:8000                 
                    https://lamp.lndo.site                     

    CONSOLE URLS    http://beanstalk.lamp.lndo.site:8000       
                    https://beanstalk.lamp.lndo.site           

   lando info
```

No error messages directly in here, it just fails and stops. When I run `lando start` again, I get:

```
   error:  Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/ctamayo/.lando/services/config/scripts/add-cert.sh'
       at Error (native)
       at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
       at copyFileSync (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy.js:16:16)
       at copySync (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy.js:85:7)
       at /usr/lib/lando/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy.js:91:7
       at Array.forEach (native)
       at Object.copySync (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy.js:90:14)
       at moveConfig (/usr/lib/lando/plugins/lando-services/lib/services.js:65:10)
       at module.exports (/usr/lib/lando/plugins/lando-services/lib/services.js:134:16)
       at AsyncEvents.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/lando/plugins/lando-services/lib/bootstrap.js:21:43)
       at AsyncEvents.handle (/usr/lib/lando/lib/events.js:109:19)
       at /usr/lib/lando/lib/events.js:170:19
       at tryCatcher (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       at Object.gotValue (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:155:18)
       at Object.gotAccum (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/reduce.js:144:25)
       at Object.tryCatcher (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
       at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
       at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
       at Async._drainQueue (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
       at Async._drainQueues (/usr/lib/lando/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
```

NOTE: This only happens when I tell Lando to run the plugin via `~/.lando/config.yml` (see below). Without that plugin referenced, the bash script runs for hours without stopping.

### Questions Abound

**How do I go about further debugging stuff?** Do I need to call `strace` from within my bash script? Is there some other system call besides `chown` and friends that might be doing this? **And just what the heck is the significance of `82`**?

[image: Yes, it's 82.]

Thanks in advance (for all the fish).

### Lando config stuff

Not sure how relevant this will end up being, but here is my LAMP application's Lando config:

```
# ~/workspace/lamp/.lando.yml
name: lamp
recipe: lamp
config:
  webroot: www
services:
  cache:
    type: redis
    persist: true
  queue:
    type: beanstalkd
    portforward: 11333
  console:
    type: beanstalkd_console
proxy:
  console:
    - beanstalk.lamp.lndo.site
tooling:
  redis-cli:
    service: cache
```

And my ~/.lando/config file, which tells lando to load my custom `lando-beanstalkd` plugin (which lives in `~/.lando/plugins/lando-beanstalkd`):

```
plugins:
  - lando-core
  - lando-events
  - lando-proxy
  - lando-recipes
  - lando-services
  - lando-tooling
  - lando-beanstalkd
logLevelConsole: warn
logLevel: debug
```

### UPDATE: Troubleshooting v2.0

So. The plot thickens. **It's changing ownership on my `~/.ssh` directory as well.**

```
total 44
drwxr-xr-x  2      82      82  4096 Nov 28 14:40 .
drwx------ 79 ctamayo ctamayo  4096 Dec 15 15:06 ..
-rw-------  1      82      82   472 Nov 28 14:40 config
-rw-------  1      82      82  1766 Jun 19 13:20 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1      82      82   410 Jun 19 13:20 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1      82      82 14600 Nov 28 14:40 known_hosts
-rwx------  1      82      82  3239 Oct 24 12:31 lando_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1      82      82   750 Oct 24 12:31 lando_rsa.pub
```

Like, WTF.

Anyway, just to throw this out there, there are zero references to `chown`, `chmod`, or `chgrp` in my plugin code. There are [a few in Lando itself](https://github.com/lando/lando/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=chown&type=). Those first couple GitHub search results seemed relevant, so I added this code to the `sh` scripts (load-keys.sh and user-perms.sh) in question:

```
if [ $LANDO_WEBROOT_USER = 82 ]; then
  echo '$LANDO_WEBROOT_USER is 82! Bailing...'
  exit 1
fi

if [ $LANDO_WEBROOT_GROUP = 82 ]; then
  echo '$LANDO_WEBROOT_GROUP is 82! Bailing...'
  exit 1
fi
```

Running my bash script again produces the same output. No mention of either `$LANDO_WEBROOT_USER` or `$LANDO_WEBROOT_GROUP`. Those scripts seem to run inside of a container, though, so their output may be suppressed...stay tuned for more...

Comment: 82 is the default user for www-data for nginx and apache in alpine linux, probably used by your containers. lando scripts/user-perms.sh does a chown -R to set the lando mount folder to lando settings (LANDO_WEBROOT_USER:LANDO_WEBROOT_GROUP) so that's probably applying to your host directory mount.